# CSS - transitioning different parts of a border in a staggered manner

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS/HTML:

In which when I hover over a div, I would like to transition the left border, then the top border, then the right border, then the bottom border on hover. Rather than all at once. I am only able to transition one side of the border, not each separately.

This is my CSS:

```
#box{
    position : relative;
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    background-color : gray;
    border : 5px solid black;    

    transition : border-left 500ms ease-in;
    transition : border-top 500ms ease-out;
    transition : border-right 500ms ease-in;
    transition : border-bottom 500ms ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

#box:hover{
    border-left : 10px solid red;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-right : 10px solid red;
    border-bottom : 10px solid red;
}
```

this is the HTML:

```
<div id="box">roll over me</div>
```

Is there a way to achieve that? (using CSS/HTML only)

http://jsfiddle.net/rtcH9/

Using the inspector I see that the other properties of the transition are essentially disabled:

[image]

Why is that? Can we not transition each property separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list them out in a single `transition`

```
transition : border-left 500ms ease-in,
             border-top 500ms ease-out,
             border-right 500ms ease-in,
             border-bottom 500ms ease-out;
```

I missed the fact that you wanted a delay between each animation. To do that add a delay time in each transition event.

```
transition : border-left 500ms ease-in 0.5s,
             border-top 500ms ease-out 1s,
             border-right 500ms ease-in 1.5s,
             border-bottom 500ms ease-out 2s;
```

Thanks @Paulie_D and @ImagineStudios for bring that to my attention.

Here is @Paulie_D's [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtcH9/5/)

Comment: The OP is not asking how to do this, he wants the sides to fade in one after another

Comment: @ImagineStudios I realized that when Paulie_D posted the fiddle. Thanks for clarifying though. See my edit.